# Why doesn't explicit COLLATE override database collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, internationalization, collation, codepages

I am on SQL Server 2008 R2 dev, server default collation is Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

Executing in SSMS
    SELECT 'éÉâÂàÀëËçæà' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
or

```
SELECT 'éÉâÂàÀëËçæà' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

outputs

- eEaAaAeEc?a on(in ocntext of/use dbName) of database with default collation Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
- éÉâÂàÀëËçæà on database with default collation Latin1_General_CI_AS

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those character literals in your queries are first converted to varchar strings under whatever collation the database is set for, and then your [collation cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) takes effect.

If you want to pass such character literals and ensure all characters are faithfully represented, it's better to pass them as nvarchar literals:

```
create database CollTest collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
go
use CollTest
go
SELECT 'éÉâÂàÀëËçæà' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS   
SELECT 'éÉâÂàÀëËçæà' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
go
SELECT N'éÉâÂàÀëËçæà' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS   
SELECT N'éÉâÂàÀëËçæà' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
go
```

Output:

```
-----------
eEaAaAeEc?a

(1 row(s) affected)


-----------
eEaAaAeEc?a

(1 row(s) affected)


-----------
éÉâÂàÀëËçæà

(1 row(s) affected)


-----------
éÉâÂàÀëËçæà

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this character table](http://www.collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0419.1251.Cyrillic_General_CI_AS.html) Cyrillic_General_CI_AS doesn't contain the `æ` chacter.  This would explain why you see a `?` in it's place if you are truly using the defaults instead of what you have in your select statements.