# How to compare symbols by collation different from database default collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, collation

Subquestioning the answer to my other question:

- ["Those character literals in your queries are first converted to varchar strings under whatever collation the database is set for, and then your collation cast takes effect."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211750/why-doesnt-explicit-collate-override-database-collation/4212898#4212898)

How to better compare 2 (non-N') symbols using explicitly a collation which is different from a default database collation?

Update: I need to compare char() or varchar() values I extracted from a database  and put them into variables @s1 and @s2

```
use dbName;
--here I alternated different db names with different collations

declare @s1 nchar(1)='à'
declare @s2 nchar(1)='a'
select   
  case 
    when @s1 <> @s2 Then 'a is NOT equal à'
    else 'a is equal to à'
  end  
collate latin1_General_CS_AS
```

outputs

- a is equal to à (on database with LATIN1_General_CI_AI default collation)
- a is NOT equal à (on db with LATIN1_General_CI_AS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it how to collate the strings 'a is NOT equal à' and 'a is equal to à', rather than for the comparison:

```
declare @s1 nchar(1)='à'
declare @s2 nchar(1)='a'
select   
  case 
    when @s1 <> @s2 collate latin1_General_CS_AS Then 'a is NOT equal à'
    else 'a is equal to à'
  end
```

Comment: Is it possible to override default database collation for a block of operations instead of writing COLLATE in each statement?

Comment: @vgv8 - I'm not aware of any way to do so - the help for collate, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx, only indicates 3 places it can be used (DB definition, column definition, and collation casts, which are what we're doing here).